# How to turn off Bonjour?

Tags: imac, crash, bonjour

My iMac (late 2009 with Mavericks) can only start up in safe mode. I have read that it might be related to a mdns responder issue.

The log comes back with 2 kinds of lines which look suspect (but I am totally novice at this!):

```
May  4 20:39:43 Macs-iMac-3.local racoon[146]: failed to bind to address fd20:c40d:6b6d:9361:80a:aacb:6d80:2d86[500]: because interface address is/was not ready (flags 2)
+
May  4 20:39:24 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FE4FA01AD60 Macs-iMac-3.local. (Addr) that's already in the list
May  4 20:39:24 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FE4FA01B1F0 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa. (PTR) that's already in the list
May  4 20:39:24 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FE4FB801B60 Macs-iMac-3.local. (AAAA) that's already in the list
May  4 20:39:24 Macs-iMac-3.local mDNSResponder[35]: mDNS_Register_internal: ERROR!! Tried to register AuthRecord 00007FE4FB801FF0 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.8.E.F.ip6.arpa. (PTR) that's already in the list
```

I would like to try and turn off bonjour by using the Apple instructions http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3789
But I don't know where to put the line `<string>-NoMulticastAdvertisements</string>` in the mdnsresponder.plist.

Here is my plist. Where should I place this line?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.mDNSResponder</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>InitGroups</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_mdnsresponder</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>_mdnsresponder</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder</string>
    </array>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.mDNSResponder</key>
        <true/>
               <key>com.apple.mDNSResponder.dnsproxy</key>
               <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockFamily</key>
            <string>Unix</string>
            <key>SockPathName</key>
            <string>/var/run/mDNSResponder</string>
            <key>SockPathMode</key>
            <integer>438</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <true/>
    <key>BeginTransactionAtShutdown</key>
    <true/>
    <key>POSIXSpawnType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it as a program argument. I've added it to the plist below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.mDNSResponder</string>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>InitGroups</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>_mdnsresponder</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>
    <string>_mdnsresponder</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/mDNSResponder</string>
        <string>-NoMulticastAdvertisements</string>
    </array>
    <key>MachServices</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.apple.mDNSResponder</key>
        <true/>
               <key>com.apple.mDNSResponder.dnsproxy</key>
               <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>Sockets</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Listeners</key>
        <dict>
            <key>SockFamily</key>
            <string>Unix</string>
            <key>SockPathName</key>
            <string>/var/run/mDNSResponder</string>
            <key>SockPathMode</key>
            <integer>438</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>EnableTransactions</key>
    <true/>
    <key>BeginTransactionAtShutdown</key>
    <true/>
    <key>POSIXSpawnType</key>
    <string>Interactive</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thanks. The file says I don't have permission to make modifications. How can I do them ?

Comment: Forget it, I found out, adding myself in the folder and file permissions !